# SSl for a Ruby Website

Tags: ssl-certificate, ruby-on-rails

How to install a SSl certificate for a Ruby website where in the same Linux web server PHP blog is running?

Both the primary website(Ruby) "www.example.com" and Blog(php) blog.example.com are running on port 80. We use two network cards and two IPs for both the application to run on port 80.

We have to secure the primary domain www.example.com (Ruby Application) using this SSL certificate.

Please Suggest.

Comment: If what you want is HTTPS, any configuration is identical whatever the application, and belongs to the webs erver. Which http server are you using ? Apache ? Nginx ? Lighttpd ?

Comment: Yes we need HTTPS for the primary domain. We use Apache Web server.

Comment: There are a lot of extensive guides on the internet about how to setup apache with mod_ssl to make apache work with SSL. Here are apache official howtos : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html